# Launching linkedin from flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have users link their linkedin accounts with a profile that they have made on my flutter app. Just to clarify all I want is there to be a link on users profiles for their linkedin account and Avvo account I am not using these as a form of authentication. I have gotten this to work but I feel this is not very user friendly and kind of a hacky way. Right now I use url-launcher to open the users profile page. Initially to link their accounts the user has to provide the url for their linkedin and Avvo accounts this is the part I don't like. There is not much code involved but ill include it.

```
  Future<void> openLinkedin(String linkedinUrl) async {
    if (await canLaunch(linkedinUrl)) {
      await launch(linkedinUrl);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not open the url.';
    }
  }
```

Is there a better way of getting the users url than having them enter it.
Or is there a better way of implementing this altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making users leave your app, try using WebView Widget as show below

```
.
.
WebView(
    initialUrl: 'https://flutter.io',  
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
),
.
.
```

Comment: Bad practice. As a matter of security, users should never be logging into a WebView within an app. If anything, [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) can be used. That way the user will already be signed in from their browser session.

Comment: Makes sense, but wcyankees24 was asking for more appealing UX sollution

Comment: Thank you this does appear to be what I need. I am currently reading the docs.

Comment: after reading more it works for displaying the profile but i still have the issue of how to get  the url in the first place I was hoping I could use a callback in chrome custom tabs to do this but it doesn't seem it has this functionality